# Pypi Package not installing whl and tar.gz files

Tags: python, pypi, pyo3

I created a very specific use case package written in Rust and I am matruin(with PyO3) to develop the package and publish it. I did [publish](https://pypi.org/project/ses-shat-graph-compute/#files) the package using maturin to Pypi and I can see the .whl and tar.gz files in the download files section but when I tried to do pip install in my project and I checked the venv folder I saw only these files under the package name: [image: these]

The code builds and runs fine on local environment but after publishing it to Pypi it does not seem to work. Command I used to publish was
`maturin publish -u __token__ -p pypi_api_key`

I tried to re build and republish the package as well but it isn't working either. Any help is appreciated and if neeeded, more information can be provided.